# How to remove Header from UITableView for particular row in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, header

I have a `tabelview` with Plain style. I have to added headers from each row. Each header should have different values. I assign the values to headers from `NSMutableArray`. The `NSMutableArray` may have null values from `WebService`. If the values from `NSMutableArray` i need to hide or remove the header for the particular row. This is my tableview design,

```
Header(Data)
Name:iPhone
Company : Apple
Header(Data)
Name:iPod
Company : Apple
Header(Null) // I want to remove this header from the tableview
Name:iPad
Comapany : Apple
Header(Data)
Name:iMac
Comapany : Apple
```

How can remove the particular header when the data is Null? Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can it by two ways:-

1) Set the Height of the header view 0 for the null value

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

2) You have to return nil from the `viewForHeaderInSection` method and call `[myTableView reloadData]`